# SocketException when connecting to HttpURLConnection after accessing HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I have a function which uses an HttpUrlConnection to call up a service on a remote client. This function works fine, until we added a new secure remote client which can only be called using HttpsUrlConnection.

Calling the new https remote client works fine, after calling the new client, the old client will return a `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` when trying to get the InputStream object.

My code look something like this:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
out = conn.getOutputStream();
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
writer.write(strJson);
writer.close();
in = conn.getInputStream();  // connection reset error here.
reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
rd = new BufferedReader(reader);
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result += line;
}
rd.close();
in.close();
reader.close();
out.close();
conn.disconnect();
```

Anyone have a clue what happened? 
Thank you in advance.

The stack trace is like so:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset 
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:891)
   at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:690)
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:661)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1324)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
```

Comment: Stack trace please.

Comment: Usually to connect Https URL you have to add the Security Certificate to your application.

Comment: Before the line "in = conn.getInputStream()", can you add conn.setDoInput(true) to indicate that the application intends to read input from the connection ?

Comment: @OTM doing like you asked to caused _java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected_ error.

Comment: Can you try moving writer.close() to where you have the close methods ?

Comment: @OTM tried it, it's not doing anything different. After digging around, I found this article : https://imhoratiu.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/httpurlconnection-over-https/ and tried to put a _System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");_ on my code, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Ok, but I what I find is when you do writer.close() it closes the socket. So, that statement should be placed after reading from the connection.

Comment: @OTM well... as I was saying, if I use the function to only call the http server, all will be fine. The error only happens once I call on the https server.

Comment: Okay, then the class needs to be HttpsURLConnection instead of HttpURLConnection. When creating and casting it needs to be HttpsURLConnection class for https server call.

Comment: @OTM the problem is that I can only connect to the problem server with HttpURLConnection. If I use HttpsURLConnection to connect to the problem server, it will fail, meanwhile the other server only accepts HttpsURLConnection. 

If I only connect to the first server, there is no problem at all and it will connect normally with HttpURLConnection. Since I need to connect to both server, I got this problem.

Comment: Ok, you may need to programmatically make the conditional switch based on the protocol (HTTPS or HTTP). When you look at the stack trace it's internally uses HttpClient, but it needs to be HttpsClient.

Comment: @OTM I've already done that of course. I'll check if the url contains https, then I'll use HttpsURLConnection, and if not, I'll use HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what caused the error to happen. My solution is just to not use the java.net.HttpURLConnection, and use org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient instead.